# Upgrade MSDE to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, msde

I am trying to upgrade an named instance of MSDE to SQL Server 2008 Express.  When I get to the "Select Features" page of the 2008 installer there are no instances listed.  The upgrade to SQL Server 2005 Express (on the same VM image) however works fine.

It seems to be a supported scenario (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx), yet I am finding that it does not work.  Has anyone successfully done this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be supported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx

There are also comments you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, so I'll post my solution for anyone that happens upon this thread;

You are probably seeing your named instance on that screen but it is greyed out.
Check that you have SP4 for MSDE, which is version 8.0.2039.